# How to extract file extension from base64 encoded file in golang?

Tags: go, base64

I want to allow users to upload files as base64 encoded. 
The results are like:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kA...
```

or

```
  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU...
```

So I'm wondering what is the idomatic way to extract the file extension from the encoded file strings?

Comment: Have a look at the [`dataturl` package](https://github.com/vincent-petithory/dataurl).

Comment: There is no file extension there, so how can it be extracted?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple enough to use string/byte functions to extract the mime type — i.e., the part between `data:` and `;base64`.

Then you can use the standard mime package to get the extension from the type:
https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#ExtensionsByType

Answer (score 0):

There is a good golang package seems to be there on github https://github.com/vincent-petithory/dataurl that gives whole information about a base64 image URI string.